# CDF of sum of $3$ independent discrete uniform random variables on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$

Tags: probability-distributions, asymptotics

What is an approximate closed formula for this probability, with a derivation:

> $p(k,n)$ is the probability, that among $n$ PC disks and $k$ errors in sum on them, there will be at least $1$ disk with at least $3$ errors? The errors are uniformly and independently distributed on the disks.

E.g. for $k=3$ errors and $n=7$ disks, $p(3,7)=1-77/\binom96=0.0833333$, if I'm right.
Here, $9=n+k-1$ and $6=n-1$, so $\binom96$ is the number of distribution of $k$ errors on $n$ disks. The distributions *themselves* are uniform. There are precisely $k$ errors altogether.

Here, $77$ were obtained via recursive equation below with appropriate border conditions:

$M(k,0)=1$, $M(k,1)=1$ for $k<3$,

$M(0,n)=1$, $M(1,n)=n$, $M(2,n)=n+\frac{n}{2}$.

The number $M(k,n)$ means that there are $M(k,n)$ possibilities of $k$ errors on $n$ disks with
the property that there are $0$, $1$, or $2$ errors on each disk.

The problem is that $M(k,n)=M(k, n-1)+M(k-1, n-1)+M(k-2, n-1)$ is infeasible to compute for larger $k$'s and $n$'s. We need a precision of about dozen digits for $k$ and $n$ being hundreds of thousands together with justification of the approximation formula. Perhaps the gamma function will be involved?

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need 12-digit precision on the probability?

Comment: 10 or 12, doesn't matter which,suffice. The point is that say 3 digits are not enough.This is the assignment. Can you come up with an approximation formula?

Comment: Sure. I just wanted to verify that it was in fact an assignment. You might want to edit the question a bit along the lines suggested at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1804/143128

Comment: @DanielWeissman Oh, that's to lengthy for me. Can you suggest to me what precisely should I read?

Comment: Really? It's not very long. Anyway, check out the "What information..." section. Besides that, it recommends that you list the reference of the quoted question (ie, the textbook if it's from one). You might want to also take a look at the last section as a warning: some people (including me) will only give hints about the derivation, so that you'll still benefit from working out the rest of it.

Comment: Do I get my offered bounty back as nobody has replied?